# Multiple users playing around with similar question

Tags: discussion, multiple-accounts

It is quite evident that the user asking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550345/proving-the-validity) is the same user that asked [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547669/how-to-show-validity-of-a-skolem-formula-in-lk).

It seems to me that this phenomenon is occurring quite often.

What we can do ?

Comment: Why is it evident? Couldn't they just be two students in the same course?

Comment: Identical questions in a short time span happen often enough. Another possibility is several students enrolled in the same course. However, there is some potential for abuse of the system so it is a good idea to flag one of the twins, and explain what you see. Mods have access to more information, and can take further action if necessary. Of course, it cannot hurt to discuss the issue, and see if we need a common policy or something.

Comment: @DanielFischer - of course ... it may be :-)

Comment: Investigating... No evidence of anything questionable yet (Daniel agrees). We keep an eye on it. Thanks for bringing this to our notice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - thanks for your effort !

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:multiple-accounts]) tag, since it seems that your question is about behavior which can indicate that one user has more than one account. Of course, if you think the tag does not fit the question, feel free to remove it.

Comment: This has been a recurring issue in the "logic" tag in particular. We have not been able to diagnose the source, but from time to time one or more people begin creating throwaway accounts and asking the same textbook questions repeatedly, often from two or three accounts. Also keep your eye out for unusual voting or bounty patterns, which have happened in the past.